# Oracle Pivot - Multi level transformation

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot

I have the below data

```
C1  C2  C3  c4

1   C   1   2
1   M   0   2
2   C   2   3
2   M   4   3
```

I want this to be pivoted as

```
C1  C2  C3  C4  C5
#   C   C   M   M
1   1   2   0   2
2   2   3   4   3
```

How do i achive this ?

Logic:
It should alway be grouped at C1 level.
C2 data will be column header for data in C3 and C4.

Comment: Could you explain the logic to get that expected output from your input data?

Comment: In a comment under an answer you proposed *" Lets say there are multiple value in C2, EX: A,B ....Z,"*. If this is a case which matters to you, you should edit your question to include such data and show what outcome you expect from it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the conditional aggregation as in the below query :

```
with t(C1, C2, C3, C4) as
(
 select 1,'C',1,2 from dual union all
 select 1,'M',0,2 from dual union all
 select 2,'C',2,3 from dual union all
 select 2,'M',4,3 from dual   
)
  select null as C1, min(C2) as C2, min(C2) as C3, max(C2) as C4, max(C2) as C5
    from t
  union all  
  select C1, 
         to_char(sum(case when C2='C' then C3 end)),
         to_char(sum(case when C2='C' then C4 end)),
         to_char(sum(case when C2='M' then C3 end)),
         to_char(sum(case when C2='M' then C4 end))
    from t
   group by C1;

 C1  C2  C3  C4  C5
 --  --  --  --  --
     C   C   M   M
 1   1   2   0   2
 2   2   3   4   3
```

Comment: Hello, Lets say there are multiple value in C2, EX: A,B ....Z, then there is no correlation between the first row and rest of the rows.

Comment: @RamKumar yes, you're right. It solves the case in your question. But it's impossible to consider a dynamic solution as long as you need to keep the first row( 
such as `null, C, C, M, M` )

Comment: @RamKumar - it is up to you to post a **representative sample** of your test data, including edge cases. It is unreasonable to ask people to provide solutions then say *"ah yes but what about this other condition I didn't mention before?"*